# vim/vimtex editing text in curly braces

Tags: brackets, braces, vim

What is the fastest way to edit the content of braces in vim.
I use the vimtex plugin.

I'm looking for a similiar way like 'cit' (change in tag) does for HTML editing.

For example:

```
\title{Some Title}   
\author{Example Name}
```

My scenario: The cursor is somewhere in the line of \title.
I want to delete 'Example Name' and get in insert mode inside of the braces as fast and easy as possible.

Comment: You might try `ci{` or `ci}` -- both do what you want in MacVim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `ci{` or `ci}` or`ciB`. Vim has the notion of `text-objects`. From `:he object-select`

> This is a series of commands that can only be used while in Visual mode or
>   after an operator.  The commands that start with "a" select "a"n object
>   including white space, the commands starting with "i" select an "inner" object
>   without white space, or just the white space.  Thus the "inner" commands
>   always select less text than the "a" commands.
>
> These commands are not available when the `+textobjects` feature has been
>   disabled at compile time.
>   Also see `gn` and `gN`, operating on the last search pattern.

The commands include

- `w` for word
- `W` for WORD
- `s` for sentence
- `p` for paragraph
- `[` or `]` for `[]` block
- `(` or `)` or `b` for `()` block
- `<` or `>` for `<>` block
- `t` for tag block
- `{` or `}` or `B` for `{}` block
- `"` or `'` or `` ` `` for quotes